# How to Scroll CollectionView to bottom Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I used this code for scrolling the collection View:

```
let section = (self.collectionView?.numberOfSections)! - 1;
let item = (self.collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: section))! - 1;
let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section);
self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true);
```

But I get error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   0]'

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 4+**

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func scrollToLast() {
        guard numberOfSections > 0 else {
            return
        }

        let lastSection = numberOfSections - 1

        guard numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection) > 0 else {
            return
        }

        let lastItemIndexPath = IndexPath(item: numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection) - 1,
                                          section: lastSection)
        scrollToItem(at: lastItemIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Should add bounds checking like the following for section and item index before scrolling to avoid potential crash...         

let lastSection = numberOfSections > 0 ? numberOfSections - 1 : 0
let lastItemIndex = numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection) > 0 ? numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection) - 1 : 0

Comment: Does this work with horizontal scrolling collection views?

Answer (score 7):

```
let lastItemIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: data.count - 1, inSection: 0)
collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(lastItemIndex, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
```

dont forget about: 
 - atScrollPosition: .Bottom
 - and you need to check is `data.count > 0` beacause `if data.count == 0` you will receive same error as you have

Answer (score 4):

You can animate your `CollectionView` to Bottom with the `contentOffset` also

Here is an example

```
let contentHeight: CGFloat = myCollectionView.contentSize.height
let heightAfterInserts: CGFloat = myCollectionView.frame.size.height - (myCollectionView.contentInset.top + myCollectionView.contentInset.bottom)
if contentHeight > heightAfterInserts {
    myCollectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: myCollectionView.contentSize.height - myCollectionView.frame.size.height), animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rajat it works but it doesn't Scroll collectionView to exactly bottom because the height of cell is dynamic.

Comment: Then you need to get the exact size.

Comment: @PRINCE you can try this also `myCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: myCollectionView.contentSize.height - myCollectionView.bounds.size.height)`

Comment: Actually i am creating a chatController i loaded some [messages](Array of String for text) to it by collectionView.reloadData(); but after i added/append new message(String message) to   [messages]  after that i called collectionView.reloadData()  after doing this The bubble size is shrink and it doesn't scroll to bottom. please @Rajat help me if you can, i am new to ios :(

Comment: You have not mentioned this things in your question, create a new question and put all the necessary information there with code, As i have answered your question here for **Scroll CollectionView to bottom Programmatically**

Answer (score 0):

```
func scrollToItem(at: IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

Can scroll the collection view contents until the specified item is visible. If item is not visible, you will get exception like Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '...

Answer (score 0):

```
var xItem:Int = 0
var currentIndex:NSIndexPath!
@IBOutlet weak var rateCollection: UICollectionView!

@IBAction func btnNextTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        xItem = xItem+1
        if xItem != arrayRateModel.count
        {
        currentIndex = NSIndexPath(item: xItem, section: 0)
        rateCollection.scrollToItem(at: currentIndex as IndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Objective-C

```
NSInteger noOfsections = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:self.collectionView] - 1;
NSInteger noOFItems = [self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:noOfsections] - 1;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:noOFItems inSection:noOfsections];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```